# VBA: lists group items of a PivotTable report

Tags: vba, pivot-table

how can I get the list of grouped items in a pivot table with VBA ?

For example, from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/group-items-in-a-pivottable-report-HP010175903.aspx#BMgroup_selected_items

how can I get

Buchanan

- 7/16/2009
- 7/23/2009
- 8/9/2009
- Etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I always wondered what `ChildItems` were, and when I saw your question it came to me...

```
Sub GetGroupedItems()
Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim ptField As Excel.PivotField
Dim ptItem As Excel.PivotItem
Dim ptChildItem As Excel.PivotItem

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
For Each ptField In pt.PivotFields
    For Each ptItem In ptField.PivotItems
        If ptItem.ChildItems.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print ptItem.Name
            For Each ptChildItem In ptItem.ChildItems
                Debug.Print ptChildItem.Name
            Next ptChildItem
        End If
    Next ptItem
Next ptField
End Sub
```

This will print the names of any grouped item, and its child items, to the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I don't know why but `ptItem.ChildItems.Count` always returns 0 ....

Instead if I check `ptItem.RecordCount` I get the correct number of child items

Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: I  bet it's because in my test the  Child items were visible.  Are they on your case, or have you unchecked the ungrouped  field?

Comment: I'm back at a computer and my guess in the previous comment is wrong. This code works for me whether the original ungrouped field is visible or not. To get a better answer, you should flesh out your question a little more, so that somebody can duplicate what you're doing.

Comment: @DougGlancy I got the same problem - `Count` shows 0 and `RecordCount` shows the correct number.   So, the code above does not print anything because `Count` is 0.  When you say that the child items were visible for you, what do you mean?  Visible as in they were not filtered?  

Sorry if that is not clear.  I can send you some test data of what I'm running into if that would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did anyone discover about the `ChildItems` showing 0?

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto Having the same problem